# Why dispatch in a component instead of an action file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

All around the web I see code dispatching directly from the component via `this.props.dispatch` passed in from the `connect` function from `react-redux`. My question is: why not simply dispatch directly from the actions file instead of just returning an action object back into the component and dispatching from there? I feel like I'm missing something here. It feels a bit wrong to dispatch directly from the component like that when we can simply call a function, pass in what's needed, and let the action creator do the dispatching for us outside of our react component.

Here's a brief example of what I mean: https://gist.github.com/overthemike/5481dab563c7f97f4151ab1c8c9cb4f1

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's really just one way to do it. Gotta choose what you like better and suits your code style.

They way I like the most is like this, with ES6:

```
import { actionA, actionB } from 'path/to/redux/actions'

class MyComponent extends React.Component { ... }

const mapStateToPros = {...}
const mapDispatchToProps = { actionA, actionB }
export default connect(mapStateToPros, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

By using shorthand notation for `mapDispatchToProps`, `MyComponent` will receive functions `actionA` and `actionB` as props, and can be called with `this.props.actionA`. `const mapDispatchToProps = { actionA, actionB }` will be interpreted by `redux` as:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    actionA: (...args) => {dispatch(actionA(...args))},
    actionB: ...,
  }
}
```

So calling `this.props.actionA()` is actually calling `dispatch(actionA())`

Comment: The only issue I see with this at all (the syntax is really nice) is that it seems to lack explicitness (especially for newcomers) in the sense that the action object is just returning a plain javascript object and the dispatch is happening behind the scenes. Trying to follow the code will never actually take you to the reducer itself which can seem confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* certainly call `this.props.dispatch()` directly in a connected component.  However, I prefer to keep my React components "unaware" of Redux by not referring to `dispatch` directly, and having them call other functions as props.  That way, the component doesn't know or care if the function was a bound Redux action creator, a callback from a parent, or a mock function in a test.

As @cfraser said, I highly recommend using the "object shorthand" syntax for passing action creators to `connect`.

You may be interested in my post [Idiomatic Redux: Why Use Action Creators?](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/idiomatic-redux-why-use-action-creators/), which goes into more details on the topic.

Per your comment about traceability: you would step backwards from the action creator being passed to the component, to the action creator definition, to the action type, to the reducers which respond to that action type.